# Ionic ion-nav-title custom content wrong display

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to acomplish this:

[image]

This is my code:

In the view I add this to the title:

```
<ion-nav-title>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="active"><div>Selección</div></div>
      <div><div>Destino</div></div>
      <div><div>Pago</div></div>
    </div>
</ion-nav-title>
```

And I use this css:

```
.bar {
    height: 60px !important;
}
.has-header {
  top: 60px !important;
}

.progress {
  line-height: 4;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.progress > div {
    display: table-cell;
}

.progress > div > div {
    color: #ddd;
    border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 50%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.progress > div.active > div {
    color: #fff;
    border-top-color: #fff;
}
```

You can play with this in codepen (please fork):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqLvMN

But I get this:

[image]

And if I change the .progress > div > div display to inline I get this:

[image]

**Help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the first image, I have made the following

**CSS changes**

```
.progress > div {
  display: inline-block; /* Horizontal alignment */
  line-height: 15px; /* Vertical alignment */
  width: 33%; /* Equal width 3 columns */
}
```

[**Updated Codepen**](http://codepen.io/ManojAMK/pen/JdazOR)

Comment: Thank you! I also remove the display: table; table-layout: fixed; from .progress because is not necessary now

Comment: Welcome Sebastian! Yes, it was not needed. I missed to remove them.

Comment: Hey @Manoj Kumar...this work wonderful in chrome emulator, but in an actual android5 device not (all appears to be aligment to something else)

Comment: I will check it on my Android device and let you know.

Comment: I think is a problem specific to y phone, I tested in a galaxy a Galaxy Note 4 with andorid 5.0.1 and looks fine...but in mi OnePlus One with Android 5.0.2 is different

Comment: Sorry, but it seems too specific and device oriented to me. Can you try opening a new question?